# count of distinct permutation of N elements when non of the given m pairs is a part of the permutation?

Tags: permutations

Suppose i am having a permutation of N items(from 1 to N) and M pairs,then what will be the no of different permutations under condition that any of M pairs should not come together?
For ex - Suppose i have N = 5,
So i have 1 2 3 4 5
Now for M = 2.and the 2 pairs are 1 2 and 4 5,the no of valid distinct permutations will be 48.
Another example say we have N = 5
So we have 1 2 3 4 5
and M = 1 and the pair is 1 2
we will have 72 valid permutations.
I am having problems when the pairs overlap, like 1 2 and 2 3.